# In SwiftUI, Why there is no `body` method for View

Tags: swiftui

I found that the SwiftUI framework is somewhat strange.
Let's focus on this example:

```
let view = VStack {
    Text("Hello")
}
view.body // Compile Error: Value of type 'VStack<Text>' has no member 'body'
```

But when I look at the declaration of `VStack`:

```
@frozen public struct VStack<Content> : View where Content : View {
    @inlinable public init(alignment: HorizontalAlignment = .center, spacing: CGFloat? = nil, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content)
    public typealias Body = Never
}
```

And the declaration of `View`:

```
public protocol View {
    associatedtype Body : View
    var body: Self.Body { get }
}
```

I will expect that `view` is of protocol `View` and should have the method `body`, but not!
Am I thinking wrong?

Comment: It is not the matter of usage, it is the matter of Swift language logic.

Comment: If all views have bodies, then it's an infinite regression - where does it stop? It stops with some primitive views' body is a special type of `Never`

Comment: Yes, the `body` of view stops at primitive view with `Body` = `Never`. But it should not prevent me from calling `body`. Call `body` with `Never` type should throw Error, but at compile time it should be legal.